# Determination of the number of checked items of the CheckedListBox, WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

In my program for WinForms I have element **CheckedListBox**.

I have two problems with it:

1. It is necessary to disable the ability to mark the new fields if already was marked 3;
2. It should not completely disable an element, like I do. If you check 3 items and then uncheck one of them, then again, it should be possible to makr one more. And I completely disable CheckedListBox. I do not know how to do it right.

[image]

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Always print '1':
    MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Count.ToString());
    if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 3)
        checkedListBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: use `CheckedIndices` instead of `SelectedItems`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well your requirements you need to handle the ItemCheck event with this code

```
private void checkListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    CheckedListBox chk = sender as CheckedListBox;
    if(e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && chk.CheckedItems.Count > 2)
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
}
```

In this way the CheckListBox is never disabled, you let your user check and uncheck at will. But when you receive the ItemCheck event you verify how many elements are checked and, if you have reached your limit, simply set the `NewValue` property of the `ItemCheckEventArgs` to an Unchecked state.

Answer (score 1):

Current answers are good and simple. Here's another approach that's a tad more involved. When a fourth item is checked, the least recently checked item is unchecked.

```
    LinkedList<int> checkedItemQueue = new LinkedList<int>();

    var clb = (CheckedListBox)sender;

    if (e.CurrentValue != CheckState.Checked && e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        checkedItemQueue.AddFirst(e.Index);

        while (checkedItemQueue.Count > 3)
        {
            clb.SetItemChecked(checkedItemQueue.Last.Value, false);
        }
    }
    else if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked && e.NewValue != CheckState.Checked)
    {
        var node = checkedItemQueue.Find(e.Index);

        if (node != null)
        {
            checkedItemQueue.Remove(node);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CheckedItems (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of SelectedItems. The later are items that you selected (made coloured) and has no connection to checking.

Concerning your second problem a simple solution might be subscribing to CheckedListBox.ItemCheck event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx). You can roll back user checking with some user friendly message here.
If disabling is what you want to perform consider two simple ListBox components with "<" and ">" buttons between them. This case you can disable button when too many items are placed to selected list.